# how can I add a category list on product page (WooCommerce )

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am creating a food menu, and I would like to add the drinks (Category) list on the burger page so the customer has to choose his drink. how it can be done with woocomerce or a plugin. Thanks

Comment: We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

To add all product list to other pages you can use woocommerce shortcut

Link - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

or add the below shortcut for that category

```
 [product_category] – Will display products in a specified product category.
 
 [product_categories] – Will display all your product categories.
```